# How to arrange dataframe as shown below into the following form?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

The below shows two images of a tweets. The first column denotes tweet IDs and second denoted the dimension reduced form of their images. But the issue is that some tweets have more than 1 images which is denoted by more than values in the second column against same tweet ids. How to do this? is there a method for this?

[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/pOsaX.png -- This is the current dataframe

[2]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/W9j14.png -- I want this into this form

Comment: Please include any relevant information [as text directly into your question](https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help), do not link or embed external images of source code or data. Images make it difficult to efficiently assist you as they cannot be copied and offer poor usability as they cannot be searched. See: [Why not upload images of code/errors when asking a question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551/15497888)

Comment: If you need assistance formatting a small sample of your DataFrame as a copyable piece of code for SO see [How to make good reproducible pandas examples](https://stackoverflow.com/q/20109391/15497888).